# How to make two $db->query from the same table with two different ORDER by column that each other stand independenty in one php page?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make two blocktables in one page from the same DB table. The first blocktable I want to ORDER it by "posted_date" column, and the second I want to ORDER it by "numviews" column. I want the both blocktables not influence each other, altough they're on the same page. Is it possible?

I have made like this,

first block

```
$popresult = $db->query('
    SELECT 
        t.id, 
        t.poster, f.id AS forum_id, 
        f.forum_name, 
        t.subject, 
        t.mainimg, 
        posted_date, 
        t.num_views 
    FROM '.$db->prefix.'forums 
    ORDER BY 'posted_date' DESC 
    LIMIT '.$numtopik.'', true) 
or error('Tidak dapat mengambil topik populer', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
```

second block

```
$popresult = $db->query('
    SELECT 
        t.id, 
        t.poster, 
        f.id AS forum_id, 
        f.forum_name, 
        t.subject, 
        t.mainimg, 
        posted_date, 
        t.num_views 
    FROM '.$db->prefix.'forums 
    ORDER BY t.num_views DESC 
    LIMIT '.$numtopik.'', true) 
or error('Tidak dapat mengambil topik populer', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());
```

but it still got error to fetch.

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

In your first query you don‘t order by the date, but use the value of `$date` in the `LIMIT` part of your query.

So your last part in your first query, should be more like:

```
[...] ORDER BY t.`yourDateColumnHere` DESC LIMIT '.$yourLimitVariableHere [...]
```

Hope that helps! If not, feel free to add a comment!

Comment: I have already update it just like your suggestion, but it till get the same error. And whenI remove one of the block its not show any problem. it seems like we can not fetch the same DB table with two diffrent $result. Can you give me more solutions? Beause I need to make them show up together. Thanks in advance

Comment: @LarasatiHabibi Can you please post the SQL error message you get? Is any of those two queries working on its own? In your edit you used single quotation marks for the posted_date column, which makes your database interpret this as a string value and not as the column. You need to replace those with backticks (`), or you can also just remove them.

Comment: Error: Tidak dapat mengambil topik populer.

Comment: @LarasatiHabibi The interesting part would be the content of  $db->error() (I thought that your error method also includes the other parameters in the error message and not only the first one).